# Why does my Azure WebApp with Auto-Swap has swap with preview by default?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, swap

I've been working for months with OctopusDeploy + AzureApp with auto-swap without any problem.

From one point this past week (I did no changes) the auto-swap has become an "auto-swap-with-preview".

What does it mean?

1. I use OctopusDeploy to "webdeploy" to my staging slot.
2. My staging slot is configured to auto-swap to production:

   - It was working perfectly since last week.
   - I did no changes for weeks. In fact I didn't use the azure portal since September.
3. What's happening now? Auto-swap is not working. I go to my web app (portal.azure.com) an shows me the message "Hay un intercambio pendiente. Haga clic en el comando Completar intercambio para completar o cancelar el intercambio" which can be translated to "There is a pending swap. Click the Complete Swap command to complete or Cancel the swap".
4. If I clic "complete swap" it shows me the swap panel with swap type set to "swap with preview" selected by default and disabled (Image attached).

   - As you can see I have 0 warnings and 2 messages
   - I complete the swap and all works perfect.
5. I've repeated steps 1-4 five times and the same happens each time.

I really don't want a preview, I just want my deployments to be auto-swapped as they have been until last week.

Any clues?

[image: azure swap panel]

Comment: Can you update your question with more details about what you are seeing? There is no such thing as 'auto swap with preview'. 'swap with preview' is always a manual step, while auto-swap is automatic, so they can't be combined. See http://ruslany.net/2015/10/azure-web-app-deployment-slot-swap-with-preview/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @DavidEbbo. I've improved the description. I know that they can't be combined, but it's what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I will talk to others and we'll respond with findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known issue with auto-swap currently that was caused by a bug in a recent update of Azure Web Apps. This error is most likely the result of that. We are deploying a fix for it.

Comment: Hi @RuslanY, this issue still happens. Is there any due date? I have 25 webapps with continuous integration (Teamcity + OctopusDeploy + Azure AutoSwap) and this issue is extremely unproductive. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Subgurim, does this repro consistently or sometimes? We've rolled out the patch last week - it is strange that you are still seeing the problem. Can you let me know your site name by following the procedure here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: The last time it happens was last Wednesday (18 of November). It happens on 25 sites of 4 completely different azure accounts and subscriptions. One of these 25 sites is https://tixalia.azurewebsites.net/ (no problem about making this url public). Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RuslanY, it seems to be solved now! Probably it has been fixed as of Wednesday. Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: Hi Subgurim, I am glad that it works for you. Although I've checked logs for that site for 11/18 and did not find any errors. Can you give me smaller timeframe when the failures happened? Also I see in our logs that the recent auto-swaps were successful, but one swap failed once and then succeeded on retry. It failed because the swap warm up request to that site timed out. Was there a problem with the application that caused the time outs?

Comment: Hi @RuslanY. On 11/18 I deployed at 11:18 PM and 17:07 PM (UTC). I already detected the timeout and the autoswap retry. I really don't know what happened, but it seems a temporary problem. On the other hand I've detected another [bug?] on azure portal (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876515/portal-azure-com-webapp-panel-without-info-tabs). Where should I report this kind of issues! Thank you very much for your attention.