# portal.azure.com WebApp Panel without info/tabs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I have 4 different azure accounts, each on with its own subscription and 5 WebApps on each subscription.

On my last created account+subscription+WebApps something really strange is happening in the "WebApp Panel" of the portal.azure.com: when I select any of my webapps the panel does not have the usual information.

It is best explained with pictures:

A normal WebApp Panel:
[image]

A fail WebApp Panel
[image]

As you can see it doesn't contain the usual information.

For more info, I don't know if it has any sense, autoswap is not working for these WebApps :S

I've created an empty website following [these steps](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly): http://emptywebsite-for-stackoverflow.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have removed parts that users were not using often from the default web app blade, you can add any of the parts you like by click on the "Add Tile" Button and You can add a group via the "Add Group" button on the bottom and add your tiles there as well.

[image]

You should see a pane of tile that you can drag tiles from and drop on your blade. Let us know if this helps, and if you like to see any other part more often on the website blade after creating the blade. After you have customized the blade it will not change again.

The Part Gallery will look like this,
[image]

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks!!I I'd found the same solution... The problem was that when I post the question there were no way to customize the panel, i.t was enabled after a few days